# Are latent variable models the same as latent source models?

Tags: time-series, classification, latent-variable

I am interested in the [research done in this thesis](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/85399) and [accompanying paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3639). This research discusses models termed ***latent source models***. I have never heard of this specific term and the papers don't reference much else.

On page 20 of the thesis, it describes latent source models as:

> ...we propose a setting for model specification and selection in
>   supervised learning based on a latent source model. In this setting, the model is
>   specified by a small collection of unknown latent sources. We posit that the data
>   were generated by the latent sources according to a stochastic model relating latent
>   sources and observations.

I was wondering if these were the same as ***latent variable models*** [which are described here](https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/learning/latent/) and that are more commonly heard of in statistics and machine learning.

I would love if someone could clarify this confusion and, if possible, provide some references about latent source models since that is my current focus.

Comment: didn't read that, but latent variable models are UNsupervised methods.

Comment: I think I need to post more info from the thesis because there are conflicting descriptions of their model.